# Turn off laptop keyborad automatically when an external keyboard is plugged in

Tags: linux, keyboard

I am looking for a way to turn off my laptop keyboard automatically when an external keyboard is connected. I got to know a solution in this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/160945/is-there-a-way-to-disable-a-laptops-internal-keyboard) which describes a way to disable the laptop keyboard manually using the `xinput` command.

Has anyone found a way to do this? As far as I know, there is a way to do it in Windows. If a similar way exists in Linux, it will be great.

Comment: it is possible that it can be done at firmware level ... check hardware settings (BIOS)

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

On the kernel level, udev rules and an exclusive grab on the laptop keyboard input device if another keyboard is detected.

On the X level, monitor xinput events, and disable the xinput laptop keyboard, or remove it from the core keyboard.

Both of these need custom code/scripts, a good understanding of the elements you need to use, and probably a few days of fiddling to get it right. And I don't know that anybody has felt the need to do this before. So I can't give you a step-by-step description.

But it definitely can be done.